# Loop through array and separate after

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array of links which I am getting from source code. I am looping through the array with a `foreach` loop and adding the results into a new array.

The problem is: I don't want all the results in one array. But for each link a separate array after I looped over it.

The array I am looping through:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://videos.volkswagen.nl/videos/videos/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://videos.volkswagen.nl/videos/service-videos/
        )

)
```

The foreach:

```
$sourceCats = array();

        foreach ($matchesAll as $links) {
            $strSourceAll = implode("|",$links);
            $source = file_get_contents("$strSourceAll");
            htmlspecialchars($source);
            $sourceCats[] = $source;
        }
```

How the array sourceCats looks now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (source code from first link)

    [1] => (source code from second link)
)
```

How I want it to look like:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => (source code from first link)
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => (source code from second link)
            )
    )
```

I have tried a few things but nothing worked. Is the idea clear?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand. Please define what is $links , why you implode for | (pipe) and give an example of what the result should look like.

Comment: Added an example, $links is the array with the 2 links which I am looping through. I am imploding because file_get_contents can't work with an array.

Comment: wouldn't just `$links[0]`instead of imploding work well in this case?

Comment: change `$sourceCats[] = $source;` to `$sourceCats[] = [$source];`

Comment: Casimir has the best solution, thanks sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$finalsourceCats = array();
$counter_sourceCats = 0;

$matchesAll = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "http://videos.volkswagen.nl/videos/videos/"
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "http://videos.volkswagen.nl/videos/service-videos/"
    )
);

foreach ($matchesAll as $links) {
    $sourceCats = 'sourceCats';
    $sourceCats = $sourceCats . "_" . $counter_sourceCats;
    $sourceCats = array();
    $strSourceAll = implode("|", $links);
    $source = file_get_contents("$strSourceAll");
    htmlspecialchars($source);
    $sourceCats[] = $source;
    $finalsourceCats[] = $sourceCats;
    $counter_sourceCats += 1;
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($finalsourceCats);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Im getting a notice: Undefined variable: sourceCats. When I print_r counter_sourceCats, I only get the service video source code.

Comment: If possible, can you give me the "$matchesAll" result ?? Thanks.

Comment: The $matchesAll is the first array in my post, containing the 2 links. Is that what you mean by result?

Comment: the code is working perfectly fine as I've tested it. It is giving 2 different arrays on 2 different links...

Comment: Yup generates 2 arrays thanks! How Can I loop through them? Since I need to perform a regex on the source code.

Comment: I generated 2 arrays as there are 2 links in $matchesAll, and as per your requirement,

"The problem is; I don't want all the results in 1 array. But for each link a separate array after I looped over it."

Comment: Thank you sir! :)

Comment: Code updated regarding, 

"How Can I loop through them? Since I need to perform a regex on the source code."

Thanks...